# How to add a Google icon font to pseudo :before

Tags: css

I'm using Google's material design icon fonts.

However I want to overlay one fone on top of another. The idea is to add a :before or :after element and style it something like this:

```
.material-icons:before
{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    color:@accent-color;
    font-size:2.4rem;
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to incorporate this: `&#xE84E`; into the content attribute - I'm tried a number of ways as well as using a converter on CSS tricks (which doesn't seem to work).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: My mistake, single semicolor is valid, although obsolete

Comment: @Amit It is not obsolete, and no browsers have or have planned to mark it as depreciated. The colon is valid and current for CSS2/2.1 pseudo selectors, and should be used in all cases for said pseudo selectors in current projects. This is for compatibility with older browsers, and is perfectly supported in newer browsers. For CSS3 psuedo selectors however, it's fine to use ::. 

Even better however would be to use : and :: just for future proofing; when the single colon syntax is less supported.

Comment: @AndyJames - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore)

Comment: According to that page, it is CSS2 syntax, and is need to support older browsers - and is therefore not 'obsolete' and will not become depreciated for support of sites using the syntax. Use : for CSS2 for compatability, :: for CSS3 as it won't be supported otherwise, and both for most safety. I see no argument here. NEVER only use new syntaxes for older keywords.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In CSS, to specify a character you would otherwise specify in HTML with the `&` escape, for example; `&#9999;`, you must use the `\` escape, for example, `content: "\9999"`.

```
.material-icons:before {
     position: absolute;
     content: "\E84E";
     color: #882288;
     font-size: 2.4rem;
}
```

To end an escaped character explicitly, use another `\`, for example `content: "\E84E\ Hello World";`

Comment: for example in this icon "&#xE313;", we have to remove 'x' character too. we have to use like this: '\E313'

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it by referencing the original Google Font css class which is:

```
.material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: ltr;
    /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    /* Support for Firefox. */
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    /* Support for IE. */
    font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

Using SASS you can extend it and set the content using a pseudo css element:

```
ul
    &:before {
        @extend .material-icons;
        content: 'label';
    }
}
```

Comment: This uses the incorrect CSS rules for `.material-icons`, as it assumes the browser will always be Chrome. The correct CSS rules are [provided in the documentation](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#setup-method-2-self-hosting).

Comment: :before { content: 'label' } should work in all modern browsers. But agree this is not in the official documentation

Comment: That isn't the part I'm commenting on. I'm commenting on your definition for `.material-icons`. You have the version that Google serves to Chrome browsers, but not the rules Google serves to Firefox or IE.

Comment: Ah good point, have updated to include the correct cross browser css